# Bash Script that loops command line arguments

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I want to write a bash script that continually runs a program over and over incrementing the first four digits by one each time until the output of the program changes from one thing to another.

For example:

./exampleProgram userName 0000-4567-4561-4564

output: Wrong

./exampleProgram userName 0001-4567-4561-4564

output: Wrong

./exampleProgram userName 0002-4567-4561-4564

output: Correct

-Loop terminates

The last three sets of four digits will stay constant, it's only the first four that change so the worst case scenario is about 10,000 loops.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the integers, and use something like `printf` to produce a correctly formatted argument. For example

```
 for ((i=0; i < 10000; i++)); do
     printf -v sn '%04d-4567-4561-4564' "$i"
     ./exampleProgram userName "$sn"
 done
```

Comment: For some reason I am still asked for input on the command line when I use this. Could this be the way the program is set up? So as to discourage loops like this from bruteforcing a result? I am still in the loop of the script because I don't have to run it over and over again but I am prompted to enter stuff each time.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what `exampleProgram` is.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
exampleProgram() {      #demo
        echo "Debug: $1 $2" >&2
        (($RANDOM % 10)) && { echo "Wrong"; return 1; } || { echo "Correct for $1 $2" ; return 0; }
}

for i in {0000..9999}
do
        res=$(exampleProgram JohnDoe "$i-4567-4561-4564")
        [[ "$res" =~ Correct ]] && break;
done
echo "Loop terminated at ($i) - result $res"
```

prints

```
Debug: JohnDoe 0000-4567-4561-4564
Debug: JohnDoe 0001-4567-4561-4564
Debug: JohnDoe 0002-4567-4561-4564
Debug: JohnDoe 0003-4567-4561-4564
Loop terminated at (0003) - result Correct for JohnDoe 0003-4567-4561-4564
```

If the `exampleProgram` has different `exit status` it is better to check it instead of the returned string, like:

```
    res=$(exampleProgram JohnDoe "$i-4567-4561-4564")
    (( $? )) || break;
```